# How to get minimum date of each line manager against each employee

Tags: sql-server

I have an employee table where the fields are:

`Reporting_Change_date, empid, empfullname, LineManagerID,LineManager_name,` and so on.I am asked to find minimum reporting change date against each employees.

I was thinking that this problem could be solved like this:

Data

```
Reporting_Change_Date    |Emp Name      |Line Manager Name
-------------------------|--------------|-----------------
01-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
02-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
03-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
04-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
05-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Sachin
06-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Sachin
07-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Sachin
08-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |DEEpak
09-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |DEEpak
10-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |DEEpak
11-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
```

I want a Output like this:

```
Reporting_Change_Date    |Emp Name      |Line Manager Name
-------------------------|--------------|-----------------
01-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
05-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Sachin
08-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |DEEpak
11-Jan-19                |Anand Kumar   |Amitabh
```

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT Min(metricdate)MetricDate, empid, linemanagername
FROM [HR_Mart].[Mart].[hr_nonadvisorbyday]
WHERE linemanagername <> 'Craig Nixon'
   AND empid = '245531'
GROUP BY empid, linemanagername
ORDER BY metricdate
```

Comment: i am unable to post my code. it is showing an error. Please help

Comment: I have tried this code.

Comment: And what is wrong?  It looks like it should do more or less what you want with some possible column differences  -- for instance your query has `metricdate` where you say your data uses `Reporting_Change_Date`.

Comment: Code goes in your question, @AnandKumar, not the comments, please.

Comment: YOu realise that SQL and the sample data you have supplied appear to be completely unrelated, as theyn don't share any column names.

Comment: Reporting_Change_Date    vs metricdate, and empid vs Emp Name. Your query looks correct if you can sort out the column name discrepancy

Comment: How does the column names magically change between your query, and your actual output?

Answer (score 1):

you can use lag and min as below:

```
;with cte_bucket as (
    select *, sum(nextlmn) over(order by reporting_change_date) bucket from (
        select *, case when linemanager_name <> lag(linemanager_name)  over(order by reporting_change_date) then 1 else 0 end as nextlmn from #employee
    ) a
)
select min(reporting_change_date) as reporting_change_date, empfullname, linemanager_name from cte_bucket
group by empfullname, linemanager_name, bucket
```

Code below https://rextester.com/SVXZ36406

Output as below:

```
+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
| reporting_change_date | empfullname | linemanager_name |
+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
| 2019-01-01            | Anand Kumar | Amitabh          |
| 2019-01-05            | Anand Kumar | Sachin           |
| 2019-01-08            | Anand Kumar | DEEpak           |
| 2019-01-11            | Anand Kumar | Amitabh          |
+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Reporting_Change_Date is a date data type, you can use the following query:

```
    select 
    [Emp Name],   
    [Line Manager Name],
    min([Reporting_Change_Date]) as MinReporting_Change_Date
from employeetable
group by  
    [Emp Name]      
    [Line Manager Name]
```

Comment: This is what the OP has.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I have used the same query in our code. I will give a example. suppose I have joined an organization (01-Jan-19 ) under Amitabh then I moved under sachin , Deepak after some time again my reporting manager has changed and i again I came under Amitabh (11-Jan-19  ). So I want to both dates (01-Jan-19 and 11-Jan-19) that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a gaps and islands problem. The user's manager changed *back* to a previous value, so the `MIN` value is still the first time that person was their manager. One method of creating the island is using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.hr_nonadvisorbyday(ReportingDate date,
                                    EmpName varchar(50),
                                    ManagerName varchar(50));


GO
--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.hr_nonadvisorbyday
VALUES('01-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Amitabh'),
      ('02-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Amitabh'),
      ('03-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Amitabh'),
      ('04-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Amitabh'),
      ('05-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Sachin'),
      ('06-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Sachin'),
      ('07-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Sachin'),
      ('08-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','DEEpak'),
      ('09-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','DEEpak'),
      ('10-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','DEEpak'),
      ('11-Jan-19','Anand Kumar','Amitabh');

GO
--Your (heavily editted) Solution
SELECT Min(ReportingDate) MetricDate,
       EmpName,
       ManagerName
FROM dbo.[hr_nonadvisorbyday]
WHERE ManagerName <> 'Craig Nixon'
  AND EmpName = 'Anand Kumar'
GROUP BY EmpName,
         ManagerName
ORDER BY metricdate;
GO
--Solution
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT ReportingDate,
           EmpName,
           ManagerName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY ReportingDate) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpName, ManagerName ORDER BY ReportingDate) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.hr_nonadvisorbyday
    WHERE ManagerName <> 'Craig Nixon'
      AND EmpName = 'Anand Kumar')
SELECT Min(ReportingDate) MetricDate,
       EmpName,
       ManagerName
FROM Grps
GROUP BY EmpName,
         ManagerName,
         Grp;

GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.hr_nonadvisorbyday
```